# PHP: strtotime and dates beyond 19 Jan 2038

Tags: php, strtotime

Am using the strtotime function to find the difference between two given dates like this:

```
$diff_in_mill_seconds = strtotime($ToDate) - strtotime($FromDate);
$difference_in_years = round($diff_in_mill_seconds / (365*60*60*24),1);
```

This script fails when the $ToDate is beyond 2038-01-19.

The official PHP Documentation says:

> The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC

The PHP Documentation also says:

> Using this function for mathematical operations is not advisable. It is better to use DateTime::add() and DateTime::sub() in PHP 5.3 and later, or DateTime::modify() in PHP 5.2.

I cannot use DateTime::add() and DateTime::sub() as the PHP version on the server is 5.2.

So, how do I calculate the difference between two dates (beyond 2038-01-19) in years using php 5.2?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3266088/862594) confirms my intuition - The UNIX timestamp is rolling over because you're on a 32-bit machine. Switch to a 64-bit machine and you'll be able to represent dates greater than 2038 as a UNIX timestamp.

Comment: PHP 5.2 *and* not a 64bit machine? Sorry, nothing can help you. You simply need a newer version of *something*.

Comment: @Sabari `DateTime::add` specifically was introduced in 5.3.

Comment: I have answered it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012589/php-mysql-year-2038-bug-what-is-it-how-to-solve-it/38394845#38394845

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the UNIX [Y2K38 bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y2k38). It has been fixed in 64bit implementations of PHP *or* by using `DateTime::diff`, which does not use integers internally and hence does not suffer from the problem.

You need either. There's no real fix without switching platforms.