# Add years to todays date in php

Tags: php

I'm getting a weird date ('01/01/1970 00:00:00) when I run the following code in php:

```
$now = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', time());
$exp = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($now .'+100 years'));
```

Comment: I believe time goes up to 2099 with strtotime. Use `DateTime` class and `format`method.

Comment: It's possible you are running into this issue: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) does not like your format: `Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-, the date string is parsed as y-m-d.`

Answer (score 6):

I would try something like this

```
$date = new DateTime();
$exp = $date->modify('+100 years')->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code :

```
<?php
$year = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+5 years'));
echo $year;
?>
```

**Output:**

2022-06-26 13:29:07

Comment: what happen??? why you guys are given negative marks, this code is working fine right?

Answer (score 1):

Try following one.

```
$now = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime('+100 years'));
```

Output => 26/06/2117 18:58:07

Comment: this gives same result try to run this.

Comment: @NiravJoshi It is giving correct answer. please recheck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332681/add-number-of-days-to-a-date

Answer (score 0):

Try  this

```
date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime('+100 years'));
```

> Output :-

```
26/06/2117 09:31:15
```

Answer (score 0):

It because you're giving the wrong date format for this function `strtotime($now .'+100 years')` and it returns `false`.

try that:

```
echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime("+100 year"));
```

Answer (score 0):

"The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC. (These are the dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed integer.)"

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$d = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+5 years'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're apparently falling into one or both the following problems:

1. a simple formatting issue (this is wrong for sure) where, since you're using `/` as separator, `strtotime` interprets days as months and vice-versa; as you can read in the [documentation page for `strtotime` (*Notes* paragraph)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed

This can be easily fixed by changing your first line from:

```
$now = date('d\m\Y H:i:s', time());
```

to:

```
$now = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', time());
```

2. the [Year 2038 Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem). You can read about this too, in the [same documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) (same paragraph, right above the previous quote):

> The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901
>   20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC. (These are the dates
>   that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed
>   integer)

If that's your case, you better use DateTime objects (as others suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266077/php-strtotime-is-returning-false-for-a-future-date)), which do not suffer this limitation. Here's a line which should work:

```
$exp = date_format(date_create("+100 years"), 'd/m/Y H:i:s');
```

---

What is happening in your code is that:

- since you're passing a non-existing date (and maybe because of a 32-bit environment too), `strtotime` returns `false`
- when passing `false` to the second argument of the `date` function, [which expects an `int`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), `false` is cast to `0`, which makes `date` return the [Epoch Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090869/why-is-1-1-1970-the-epoch-time).

Comment: ups, I got lost trying to make the answer clear enough and did not notice that so many had already replied :/

Comment: Anyway, my answer is in line with what @aynber hinted about formatting + what [Bernhard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44761257/8200213) and [tilz0R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44760770/add-years-to-todays-date-in-php/44762681#comment76502249_44760770) said about the 32-bit limit.
My solution is very similar to [Ivan G's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44760826/8200213).

I'm still quite new on Stack Overflow: if my reply is redundant let me know and I'll delete it